# subset data based on number of characters in cell in r

Tags: r, subset

I have a data frame as like:
there are names of people, companies, institutes, and universities. All the number of characters of people's names equal to 2 or 3 (Chinese name), others' names are at least 4 characters.

I want to subset rows with at least two names that have at least 4 characters.

```
ID  V1             V2            V3            V4     V5     V6          
1   AB             BB   
2   SCV            FGB           ASA           
3   ABC            EFG Company   XXX institute
4   TTT. Company   AB            BCD
5   YYY. Company   AB            BCD           AC     EFF    DDD Company
6   HJK            KSF Company   GHJ Company   KK
```

how can I get the result:

```
ID  V1             V2            V3            V4     V5     V6                 
3   ABC            EFG Company   XXX Company
5   YYY. Company   AB            BCD           AC     EFF    DDD Company
6   HJK            KSF Company   GHJ Company   KK
```

Also, is any possibility to get the result as below:
that only keeps the cell that more than three characters and replaces the cell if it is a people’s name (characters≤3). Actually, this is what I want to get. Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

```
ID  V1             V2            V3            V4     V5     V6                 
3   EFG Company   XXX Company
5   YYY. Company  DDD Company
6   KSF Company   GHJ Company
```

Comment: Can you provide the `dput` for your dataframe or a subset of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
dat2 <- dat[rowSums(sapply(dat, nchar) > 3) > 1,]
dat2
#   ID           V1          V2            V3 V4  V5          V6
# 3  3          ABC EFG_Company XXX_institute  .   .           .
# 5  5 YYY._Company          AB           BCD AC EFF DDD_Company
# 6  6          HJK KSF_Company   GHJ_Company KK   .           .
```

The next step:

```r
dat2[,-1] <- as.data.frame(t(apply(dat2[,-1], 1, function(z) {
  out <- z[nchar(z) > 3]
  c(out, rep(NA, length(z) - length(out)))
})))
dat2
#   ID           V1            V2   V3   V4   V5   V6
# 3  3  EFG_Company XXX_institute <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 5  5 YYY._Company   DDD_Company <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 6  6  KSF_Company   GHJ_Company <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

(Replace the `rep(NA` with `rep(""` if you want an empty string ... though I generally find `NA` is better for its unambiguity in everything except report-generation/rendering tasks.)

---

I faked your data with

```r
dat <- read.table(header=T, text="
ID  V1             V2            V3            V4     V5     V6          
1   AB             BB            .             .      .      .
2   SCV            FGB           ASA           .      .      .
3   ABC            EFG_Company   XXX_institute .      .      .
4   TTT._Company   AB            BCD           .      .      .
5   YYY._Company   AB            BCD           AC     EFF    DDD_Company
6   HJK            KSF_Company   GHJ_Company   KK     .      .")
```